# How to build a PPA from a git repository?

Tags: ppa, launchpad

How can we build a PPA from a git repo? For example say that I have an icon theme hosted in Git. How can I add it to a PPA? (Note : I don't know much about Launchpad and PPAs)

Comment: To package your code into a ppa see http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/ppa/ and https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA

Answer (score 0):

The first step you want to master is how to: [Package New Software](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html).  That is taking either your compiled executables or your icon theme and turning them into a .deb package that apt-get can use.  Once you have your icons in a .deb file then see the PPA link in that same page.